# Fancybox: different width percentages - cleaner script?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I needed a 100% fancybox width for mobiles and 90% width for greater screens. I did tweak the  common script and it's working but I know it looks like a troglodyte scripting:

```
           if (windowWidth > 480) {
              $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                  openEffect  : 'none',
                  closeEffect : 'none',
                  iframe : {
                      preload: false
                  },
                  padding: 0,
                  width : '90%',
                  height : '90%',
                  helpers : {
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)'
                        }
                    }
                  }
              });
          }else{
              $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                  openEffect  : 'none',
                  closeEffect : 'none',
                  iframe : {
                      preload: false
                  },
                  padding: 0,
                  width : '100%',
                  height : '90%',
                  helpers : {
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)'
                        }
                    }
                  }
              });
        }
```

So, I'd like to know how to separete the width and height to avoid the "duplicated" definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your conditional statement inside the fancybox `afterLoad` callback like :

```
afterLoad: function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
        this.width = '90%'; // or whatever
        this.height = '90%';
    } else {
        this.width = '100%';
        this.height = '90%';
    }
}
```

Notice that, in order to get your custom dimensions, you may need to set the `fitToView` option to `false`. You may also need to adjust the fancybox margins.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4czgngwd/)**

Comment: So that's was the problem. In my last try I did place the conditional without the afterload function. Many thanks @JFK .